# PHP Form POST Variables Empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass variables from `delivery.php` to `delivery-insert.php` using HTTP POST. Upon submitting, no variables are passed in.

Below is the form in `delivery.php`

```
<form action="delivery-insert.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Delivery No.</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deliverynoinput" placeholder="D0" required> <br>
      
      <label>Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="deliverypriceinput" placeholder="0" required> <br>
      
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="deliveryquantityinput" placeholder="0" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectTruckInput">Select Delivery Truck</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selectTruckInput">
      <?php
         foreach ($trucks as $i => $value) {
             print "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
         }
         ?>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectCustomerInput">Select Delivery Customer</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selectCustomerInput">
      <?php
         foreach ($customers as $i => $value) {
             print "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
         }
         ?>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectDriverInput">Select Delivery Driver</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selectDriverInput">
      <?php
         foreach ($drivers as $i => $value) {
             print "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
         }
         ?>
      </select>
   </div>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And below is `delivery-insert.php` where I attempt to gather the POST variables.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "project";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);

if (! $con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$dno = $_POST['deliverynoinput'];
$dprice = intval($_POST['deliverypriceinput']);
$dquant = intval($_POST['deliveryquantityinput']);
$dtruck = $_POST['selectTruckInput'];
$dcust = $_POST['selectCustomerInput'];
$ddriver = $_POST['selectDriverInput'];

print '<h1>Here</h1>';
print '<h1>'.$dno.'</h1>';
print $_POST['selectTruckInput'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO delivery (deliveryno, price, truckid, custphoneno, driverid) VALUES ('$dno','$dprice','$dtruck','$dcust','$ddriver')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    print "added to delivery successfully";
} else {
    print "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO deliveryquantity (deliveryno, quantity) VALUES ('$dno', '$dquant')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    print "added to deliveryquantity successfully";
} else {
    print "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

$con->close();

?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why all my variables are empty?

Comment: Forms work with the `name` attribute, and you have none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the attribute [name](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) on your inputs. With this the browser will send the corresponding names as a key for `$_POST`. This even works for arrays!

e. g.

```
<!-- Single Value -->
<input name="someValue" />

<!-- Array -->
<input name="someArray[]" />
<input name="someArray[]" />
```

can be accessed like this:

```
// Single value
$_POST['someValue']

// Array
$_POST['someArray'][$numericIndex]
```